# Starting an activity from a notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I am working on an android app, and I am currently trying to create a notification, and once the user clicks on the notification, an activity should be launched. The notification is being created fine but the activity is not being started.

Below is the code for the notification.

```
private void showNotification(String username, String password)
{
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(ns);

    CharSequence tickerText = "Username Copied";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int icon = R.drawable.icon;

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    CharSequence contentTitle = "BPM - Login Management";
    CharSequence contentText = "Username Copied";

    Intent intentNotification = new Intent(context, CopyPassword.class);
    intentNotification.setAction(Long.toString(when));
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    intentNotification.putExtra("password", password);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

    final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

The notificiation is being generated from within a normal java class not an android activity in case this makes any difference.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you doing this...`intentNotification.setAction(Long.toString(when));`? The action of an `Intent` should be something like `ACTION_VIEW` (for example). Setting the action to some arbitrary value representing the current system time doesn't make sense.

Comment: I haven't a clue what I was doing there, I've removed that now. I've changed to use Intent.ACTION_VIEW but doesn't make a difference and just removing it completely doesn't make a difference

Comment: That code you're displaying, is it inside a broadcast receiver class?

Comment: No just a standard java class doesn't extend or implement anything on the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the setAction this isn't needed.

Try:

```
Intent intentNotification = new Intent(context, CopyPassword.class);
intentNotification.putExtra("password", password);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentNotification, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
```

Also ensure the CopyPassword Activity is declared in your AndroidManifest

I wrote a blog post about it: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/ :-D

Comment: Thanks it was because I forgot to add the activity to the manifest file. I always forget about that but for it doesn't seem to throw the exception in the log cat for starting an activity in a notification.